# sending Activity to Back and Front

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have many Activities in my android Application and SMS Service that runs in background.

My main Activity is `ZigbeeActivity.java` on which I have an Exit Button when I got click on Exit I want to application sent to background for doing this I use `MoveTaskToBack` method and now my smsService is running at background which receives sms but when I run my Zigbee Activity again from my application installed on Device it gets started, but does not show any data hold on it I think it will start new Zigbee application. Can anyone tell me how I can call my application on foreground?

The code of onCreate Method to start service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
            startService(new Intent(this,SmsService.class));
    }catch(Exception e){}

}
```

this is the code for sending activity to background

case R.id.btnExit:

```
            ConstantClass.Clear_Main_Screen = false;
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            break;
```

Comment: if you are use service and there is no task in your activity then you not need to doback. services is running only in background. so just you have to check service is running or not. for this when you start service just add some value in Preference like servicerunning = true; now when you start app again you have to check if service is running then no need to start again. in last you have to also save Preference in onDestroy service save prefrance servicerunning=false;